# Shortening DataProtection encryption length in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, encryption, data-protection

I'm quite new to .net and had a question regarding DataProtector.

When using DataProtector.Protect without any configuration, the resulting encryption becomes too long for the API I need to pass it to, I was wondering if using the configuration methods (as seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?tabs=aspnetcore2x)) would help? I tried the following in the class where I needed to protect the data:

```
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
            serviceCollection.AddDataProtection()
                .UseCustomCryptographicAlgorithms(new ManagedAuthenticatedEncryptionSettings()
                {
                    // a type that subclasses SymmetricAlgorithm
                    EncryptionAlgorithmType = typeof(Aes),

                    // specified in bits
                    EncryptionAlgorithmKeySize = 128,

                    // a type that subclasses KeyedHashAlgorithm
                    ValidationAlgorithmType = typeof(HMACSHA256)
                });

            var services = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
            _protector = services.GetDataProtector("MyClass.v1");

var protect = _protector.Protect(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myData));
```

However even after changing the EncryptionAlgorithmKeySize from the default 256 to the minimum 128, 'protect' was still resulting in an encryption of the same length which makes me think that the configuration isn't working or configuration doesn't affect encryption length.

Does anyone know if this is being done the right way or if there is a better way to reduce encryption length?

For example a simple 9 character string gets encrypted to 134 characters.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This really sounds like a bad idea. Why do you want to transfer encrypted data off the machine, and why is the API you're sending it to limited in length?

Comment: @CodeCaster the data includes an antiforgery token, but the API allows only 500 characters to be sent/passed back and forth so was just wondering if there was a configurable way to limit encryption length.

Answer (score -1):

DPAPI is meant to secure data-at-rest, not data for transmission.

Ryan Dobbs is correct, above (or below? I can't figure out how StackOverflow sorts unaccepted answers...), weakening your encryption to attain a smaller payload is a very bad idea. The right way to address this is to secure the connection (TLS-style SSL), then you can just send things plaintext, or (as Ryan suggests) drop a properly-encrypted payload somewhere that both sender and receiver can access it.

But to answer your question more directly, the payload size is controlled by the hashing function. Encryption key size only tells you the cryptographic complexity of the encryption algorithm -- how hard the encryption is to break. The part that says `HMACSHA256` is a SHA-256 hash which means it produces a 256-bit output.

`MD5` is 128-bit but it's generally insecure (only good for checksums).

The documentation says the key size and hash size must be equivalent, so you can't go to 128 bits with SHA. The shortest SHA available is the old SHA1 algorithm (`HMACSHA1`) which is 160 bits, but the expectation is that anything less than 256-bits will be insecure relatively soon. The SHA2 algorithm yields `HMACSHA256` and `HMACSHA512`.